# Permanently grouping shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm teaching myself some VBA, and have been combining shapes (in Excel), for example a rounded rectangle with another shape on it, similar to a playing card. I know I can group the shapes so they move together, but they can still come apart, as it were.

How do I permanently group them so they are one shape ever after... and can be moved as one entity via a mouse-click or code?

Comment: If you want to keep the object as a shape (not a picture), you can merge (union/intersect/ etc) shapes in powerpoint, and then copy and paste them into excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the version of excel you're using, but in 365 you can definitely copy - paste as picture, which should have the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Miller86, I tried this in Excel 2007 and it didn't work. I'll keep playing

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thanks so much, I appreciate your help.